# Extracting data from `:` till <br> using python

Tags: python, regex

```
Page load for http://xxxx?roxy=www.yahoo.com&eventto=https://mywebsite?event took 4001 ms (Ne: 167 ms, Se: 2509 ms, Xe: 1325 ms)<br><br><br>Topic: Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite<br>
```

I want to use regular expressions in python to extract the `Topic` from the above message.I want the extracted message to be `Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite`

Comment: Show us what regex you currently have and we can fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your delimiters, you can split the string instead.

```
>>> s.split('Topic: ')[1].split('<br>')[0]
'Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the RegEx `r'Topic: (.*)\<br\>'`

```
>>> s = 'Page load for http://xxxx?roxy=www.yahoo.com&eventto=https://mywebsite?event took 4001 ms (Ne: 167 ms, Se: 2509 ms, Xe: 1325 ms)<br><br><br>Topic: Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite<br>'
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'Topic: (.*)\<br\>',s).group(1)
'Yahoo!! My website is a good website | Mywebsite'
```

Note: This can be done faster using string processing than regex